# Query from table order by date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
|ID |       date          |
|-------------------------|
| 1 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34 |
| 2 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34 |
| 3 | 2020/08/03 15:21:34 |
| 4 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34 |
| 5 | 2020/08/03 15:28:34 |
| 6 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34 |
```

This is the format I use to save the current date:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');      
$date=date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); // Where $date is the value I am saving to the table.
```

I want to query and display the last 5, and show the newest on top. I tried it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y/%m/%d H:i:s') DESC LIMIT 5";
```

It displays 5 rows, but not in a order. This is the order I get it in:

```
Row 1: 2020/08/03 15:27:34
Row 2: 2020/08/03 15:27:34
Row 3: 2020/08/03 15:21:34
Row 4: 2020/08/03 15:27:34
Row 5: 2020/08/03 15:28:34
```

Ant tips?

Comment: You should use a proper date column type, instead of writing an arbitrary date format into a text field.

Comment: Yes, use the column type : datetime and order by ASC/DESC witout use function like STP_TO_DATE

Answer (score 0):

You also have to use the t´pattern reconsignition for hour, minutes and se4conds

But you should always save the date time as datetime, which also would work with your data, and only format with Date_format the output, that makes the live much more eays, besides str_to_date doesn't use indexes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `date` varchar(24)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2020/08/03 15:27:34'),
>   ('2', '2020/08/03 15:27:34'),
>   ('3', '2020/08/03 15:21:34'),
>   ('4', '2020/08/03 15:27:34'),
>   ('5', '2020/08/03 15:28:34'),
>   ('6', '2020/08/03 15:27:34');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') DESC LIMIT 5
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | date               
> -: | :------------------
>  5 | 2020/08/03 15:28:34
>  1 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34
>  2 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34
>  4 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34
>  6 | 2020/08/03 15:27:34
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c3ec5d857e757c4996d434edfefcd78a)*

Comment: I see two comments on my question says I have to change column to `date`, but I see on your answer (same as I am using today) is a `varchar`. Does it matter what type I am using?

Comment: -When you change my example to datetime , you don't need the str_to_time, as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: I see. Is there any difference? Or doesn't it really matter?

Comment: as i wrote in my answer str_to_ate can't use indexes, so it would be much slower on bigger databases

Comment: But if I change the column to `date(255)` insted of `varchat(255)`, will I still be able to store both the date and time as: `2020/08/03 15:27:34` or only the date?

Comment: use **datetime** instead of varchar(255), use teh example to see what happens when you change